# get(self) takes exactly 1 argument, 2 supplied - NOT

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blobstore

I am having a very odd error occurring in the following:

```
class ServeHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler):
def get(self, resource):
    iconKey = str(urllib.unquote(resource))

    if iconKey:
        blob_info = blobstore.get(iconKey)

        if blob_info:
            url = images.get_serving_url(blob_key=iconKey, size=200)

            self.response.out.write('<h1>%s</h1><small>%s</small><br/><br/><img src="%s" alt="%s">' % ('A Title', '11-26-1997', url, 'A Title'))
```

The response is this:

```
TypeError: get() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

The code is suposed to take the end of the URL request, pass that to the `iconKey` var, and use it as a blob key to access the blobstore for the image and create a serving url with the `images.get_serving_url()` method.

Anybody run into this before? I tried putting a `@staticmethod` parameter over the `get` definition, but of course, that made the `get` method not be able to access the request via `self`.

**EDIT**

I just changed something which got another error. I had been using the `([^/]+)?` regexp for the URL - where the URL would be `/view/icon/76M5e-xIStHRJDYyXBXjDA==` and the resource passed to the `get()` method would be the `76M5e-xIStHRJDYyXBXjDA==` ending of the URL.

I just change the regexp to `(.*)` as per @systempuntoout's answer below. Now I get this error: `AttributeError: split` with this stack trace:

```
ERROR    2011-07-15 13:19:39,949 __init__.py:463] split
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/mac/Desktop/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/webapp/__init__.py", line 700, in __call__
handler.get(*groups)
File "/Users/mac/icondatabase/main.py", line 72, in get
iconKey = str(urllib.unquote(self.request))
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/urllib.py", line 1164, in unquote
File "/Users/mac/Desktop/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webob/webob/__init__.py", line 500, in __getattr__
raise AttributeError(attr)
AttributeError: split
INFO     2011-07-15 13:19:39,958 dev_appserver.py:4217] "GET /view/icon/76M5e-xIStHRJDYyXBXjDA== HTTP/1.1" 500 -
INFO     2011-07-15 13:19:40,250 dev_appserver.py:4217] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Comment: Can you include the entire stacktrace, please, along with the route definition for this handler? And are you sure you're not seeing this error against a different version from before you added the `resource` parameter to `get()`?

Comment: is that a typo in your source formatting or have you indented your code incorrectly?, which would result in the error you are seeing.

Comment: @Chris - Yes, a typo.

@Nick - will update with stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably not matching any `resource` group parameter in your URL regex configuration.

Be sure to have a rule like this in your main:

```
 application = webapp.WSGIApplication(
          [(r'/files/(.*)', ServeHandler)], debug=True)
    run_wsgi_app(application)
```

This will pass to the get() `resource` parameter of the ServeHandler instance, the string matched after the route `/files/`.

Example:
`localhost:8080/files/A2312ODESDX` will pass `A2312ODESDX` as `resource`

Comment: Aha!! Now at least I get another error... `AttributeError: split`. Haven't Googled it yet.

Comment: the error says `iconKey = str(urllib.unquote(self.request))`, your code says `iconKey = str(urllib.unquote(resource))`

Comment: Garh!! Now it gives me that unhelpful "`NotImplementedError: Unable to find the Python PIL library.`"

Comment: ok, now we are close to see something. You should install PIL in order to use the `google.appengine.api.images`
module in the development server.

Comment: Aha!! Thank you very much... lemme go try that.

Comment: @Crossdiver Have you checked?

Comment: YES, and it turns out I didn't have PIL installed on the dev server... you gotta hate those super simple problems that you sweat over. :P

Answer (score 0):

You'fre confusing the `get` methods of two different classes:

- `BlobstoreDownloadHandler.get` has two arguments, `self` and `resource`.
- `webapp.RequestHandler.get` takes only `self`

Comment: But I am using the `BlobstoreDownloadHandler.get` method, and the `resource` argument.

Comment: Changing the handler to `webapp.RequestHandler` and removing the `resource` argument had no affect.

Comment: @Crossdiver I'm assuming the problematic line is `blob_info = blobstore.get(iconKey)`. What is `blobstore` in this context? What is its type?

Comment: `BlobstoreDownloadHandler` is a subclass of `RequestHandler`. `RequestHandler.get()` can take any number of arguments - the arguments it gets depends on what regular expression groups there were in the matching URL pattern.